# Transparent Data Encryption doesn't appear to start encrypting the DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, transparent-data-encryption

I have enabled TDE on a big DB of mine (mdf file:9.6GB, log file:12.6GB).

I have followed the steps from this video (amongst other sources):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EhCeLbAS_o

It has been more than 1.5 hour, and when running [the query to check on the status](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-monitor-and-manage-transparent-data-encryption-tde-in-sql-server/), the progress appears to be zero!

```
     SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName, encryption_state,
     encryption_state_desc =
     CASE encryption_state
              WHEN '0'  THEN  'No database encryption key present, no encryption'
              WHEN '1'  THEN  'Unencrypted'
              WHEN '2'  THEN  'Encryption in progress'
              WHEN '3'  THEN  'Encrypted'
              WHEN '4'  THEN  'Key change in progress'
              WHEN '5'  THEN  'Decryption in progress'
              WHEN '6'  THEN  'Protection change in progress (The certificate or asymmetric key that is encrypting the database encryption key is being changed.)'
              ELSE 'No Status'
     END,
     percent_complete, encryptor_thumbprint, encryptor_type
     FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

[image: TDE Progress results]

I have checked the value of the 5004 trace flag ([which is said to be able to pause the encryption and produce similar results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples)), and it is not set:

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS (5004);
```

[image: State of 5004 trace flag]

This is the second time I try to enable encryption on the same restored backup, and on both times I got the same delay. So, I am beginning to wonder if I am missing something here.

Does anyone have any ideas if this delay to see some progress is to be expected?
If not, any ideas on what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I still can't make this work. SQL Server aborts the encryption process without reporting the reason. I took a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#enable-tde) and didn't get much wiser. These are the steps I've used the last time, while trying to be extra careful :

```sql
        -- I regenerate all keys, just in case:
        ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY FORCE REGENERATE;
        GO
        OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
        GO
        ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
        -- If it doesn't exist already: CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
        GO
        -- Restart SQL Server Service
        -- Restore Backup
        -- Change compatibility level for the newly created DB to 2017
        -- Restart SQL Server Service
        -- Create certificate:
        use master;
        GO
        OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
        GO
        CREATE CERTIFICATE SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificate WITH SUBJECT = 'SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificate';
        -- 
        USE SECURED_DB;
        GO
        CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
        ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificate;
        GO
        -- Backup keys and certificates.
        use master;
        go
        backup certificate SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificate to file= 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificate'
        with private key (file = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\SECURED_DB_EncryptionCertificateKey.pvk', encryption by password = 'mypass');
        go
        -- Avoid having active connections to DB
        USE master;
        -- Encrypt DB
        ALTER DATABASE SECURED_DB SET ENCRYPTION ON;
```

At this point, the SECURED_DB encryption gets aborted, and restarting the SQL Server service makes `master` lose its encryption and `SECURED_DB` gets into permanent recovery mode.

Comment: What is `encryption_scan_state` and/or `encryption_scan_state_desc` column?

Comment: What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) show it's waiting on? A 10 GB database is tiny, 1.5 hours sounds like something is wrong.

Comment: @J.D. It returns no results when doing `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive` on the `master` DB (using version 12 of `sp_WhoIsActive`). But I had this issue while "installing" `sp_WhoIsActive`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71720321/how-to-install-sp-whoisactive-procedure . Probably it is not related, since the first time I tried I didn't have `Always Encrypted` turned on.

Comment: What about [`sp_BlitzWho`](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sp_blitzwho/)?...does it return it any results and what are the session wait stats for those results?

Comment: @Charlieface I think those columns were added on a later version of SQL Server. I use SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @J.D. Nope. `sp_BlitzWho` returns no results either. :\

Comment: What kind of disk does your server use? Are other I/O intensive tasks slower than usual too by any chance, e.g. restoring a backup? For reference, a 10 GB database backup on a modern SSD (not even NVMe) shouldn't take more than about 20ish seconds.

Comment: This information is just not available then. I guess you just have to wait til it's finished. Is there disk activity?

Comment: @J.D. This is a developer machine running the Developer version of SQL Server 2017. The disk is a simple SSD disk on a laptop. I see no noticeable and related disk activity on Task Manager and Process Explorer. Any idea if a particular SQL Server service, apart the main SQL Server instance, needs to be running? I had SQL Server Browser and SQL Server Agent stopped.

Comment: You'd likely see I/O activity for the main SQL Server service. Again, does I/O generally appear to be slow on that SSD?...How long did it roughly take to restore the 10 GB database backup?

Comment: @J.D. Restoring the backup took a few seconds. One minute tops. And the I/O on `sqlservr.exe` seems flatlined.

Comment: I've now tried disabling my anti-virus software (just in case), and then doing `DBCC TRACEON(5004); DBCC TRACEOFF(5004); DBCC TRACESTATUS (5004); ALTER DATABASE SECURED_DB SET ENCRYPTION ON;`. Still nothing.

Comment: Also tried encrypting a smaller DB (in the order of 100 MB) now. I got the same problem. I believe that the only thing I had to do differently compared to the video, was to open the existing master key in my DB, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Whenever I enable the encryption I get this in the log file at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG` :  `2023-06-21 17:57:47.85 spid36s     Beginning database encryption scan for database 'SECURED_DB'.
2023-06-21 17:57:47.85 spid36s     Database encryption scan for database 'SECURED_DB' was aborted. Reissue ALTER DB to resume the scan.`. So, for some reason it aborts the process.

Comment: This hint made me discover that my DB compatibility was low : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497117/sql-server-2016-tde-database-encryption-scan-for-db-name-was-aborted But I am not sure if that is the only problem.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/232330/220697 Are you sure you actually have access to the encryption certificate? Try `ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE`

Comment: @Charlieface Nope. `ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY REGENERATE; ALTER DATABASE SECURED_DB SET ENCRYPTION ON;` doesn't help. It still aborts the encryption. And with compatibility level for the DB set to 2017 this time... :(

Comment: @Charlieface And this didn't help either: `OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypass';
ALTER DATABASE SECURED_DB SET ENCRYPTION ON;`

Comment: I've found a similar or identical post, with no solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244685/where-can-i-find-the-reason-why-tde-encryption-scan-aborted . It brings me joy I am not alone in this...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out what was wrong, although I am not sure I understand it...

All I had to do was drop my pre-existing master key and not re-use it.

The funny thing is that regenerating the master key (which was something I tried from early-on) didn't help either.

This feels so weird to me, but not weirder than the fact that MS does not log the exact reason for aborting the encryption in the log file.